# Can't import Divi layouts in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Trying to import Divi layouts (.json files)
Getting this error:

```
This file cannot be imported. It may be caused by file_uploads being 
disabled in your php.ini. It may also be caused by post_max_size or/and 
upload_max_filesize being smaller than file selected. Please increase 
it or transfer more substantial data at the time.
```

This is not the case, however as I don't have a limit on either and I can upload anywhere else within my WP installation.

Does anyone have any idea what else would cause this error?

Comment: How big are the files you're trying to upload? On the server the site is running on you may be able to increase the limit with a GUI, otherwise, find the php.ini file and check the file-upload settings. Or you could break the `.json` file apart into smaller ones. Does adding: `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');` to `wp-config.php` help?

Comment: The files are about 1M and like I said, there are no limits. Uploading the Divi themes itself (18M presented no problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My response pertains to Divi Theme Version 3.0.46

I had the same problem, and what follows is how I fixed it.

In my case the error is being generated from the Divi Builder portability.js file, line 464:

```
var fileSize = Math.ceil( ( data.file.size / ( 1024 * 1024 ) ).toFixed( 2 ) ),
    formData = new FormData();

// Max size set on server is exceeded.
if ( fileSize >= $this.postMaxSize || fileSize >= $this.uploadMaxSize ) {
    etCore.modalContent( '<p>' + $this.text.maxSizeExceeded + '</p>', false, true, '#' + $this.instance( '.ui-tabs-panel:visible' ).attr( 'id' )\
    );

    $this.enableActions();

    return;
}
```

The thing to note here is, this script is rounding the max upload sizes to whole numbers of MB.

So my max file size for this site was 2MB, and my file is 1,495,679 bytes, which the script turned into:

```
if 2>=2 {
    // throw an error
}
```

So it seems, the solution is to make **both** your php upload max size and max post size **at least 1MB** greater than the file you are trying to upload.

The Elegant Themes people have a lengthy post on this:

https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/is-the-wordpress-upload-limit-giving-you-trouble-heres-how-to-change-it

This is as simple as setting this in my php.ini.

```
; TO have a 31.4MB file upload into Divi, these must be at least 32MB.
post_max_size = 32M
upload_max_filesize = 32M
```

The final thing I want to say about this as since this error is generated by javascript in the browser, you must:

- change your php.ini
- restart your webserver [at least I needed to w/ Apache]
- refresh the page, as the limits are cached in the browser, not the result of any sort of ajax call, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.I googled and found the solution below.(Apology for not having a proper explanation!)

Solution:
Create a new file `php.ini` with the following text & save in website's root directory and it's done.

```
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 100M
```